# Select specific fields from collection within collection in mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection of Person in Mongodb which has structure like this:

```
class Person
{
   public string { get; set; }
   public Address houseAddress { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
   public string streetNumber { get; set; }
   public City currentCity { get; set; }
}

class City
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to only select City subfield of person. I tried using excluding and including but not working. Would anyone tell me what is the correct way to do this in C#

I have tried this code:

```
string jsonQuery = @"{}, {'houseAddress.currentCity' : 1, _id:0}"; 
BsonDocument query = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonQuery);
var sQuery = new QueryDocument(query);
var cities = dbConnection.Person.FindAs<Person>(sQuery).SetFields(Fields.Include("currentCity"));
```

Comment: Instead of `currentCity` at your `Fields.Include()` call, isn't it `houseAddress.currentCity`?

Comment: @FelipeSabino If that works then it should probably be `houseAddress.currentCity.Name` (the actual `string` contained in the `City` object).

Comment: @Quantic exactly! thanks for pointing it out